# How do you make labels on a slider change colors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, anythingslider

I did not build this slider and I don't know much JS/jQ. We changed the image for the slider buttons and now they all turn orange and stay orange. I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is the site:

http://www.howlatthemoon.com/

And here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){

  var tab1 = jQuery('.featured-tabs .tab1').text();
  var tab2 = jQuery('.featured-tabs .tab2').text();
  var tab3 = jQuery('.featured-tabs .tab3').text();
  var tab4 = jQuery('.featured-tabs .tab4').text();
  jQuery('.featured-tabs').remove();

  var image1 = jQuery('.featured-images .image1').html();
  var image2 = jQuery('.featured-images .image2').html();
  var image3 = jQuery('.featured-images .image3').html();
  var image4 = jQuery('.featured-images .image4').html();
  jQuery('.featured-images').remove();

  $('#slider .panel1').empty().append(image1);
  $('#slider .panel2').empty().append(image2);
  $('#slider .panel3').empty().append(image3);
  $('#slider .panel4').empty().append(image4);

  $('#slider').show();

        $('#slider').anythingSlider({
            startStopped        : false,
            width               : 768,   // if resizeContent is false, this is the default width if panel size is not defined
            height              : 255,   // if resizeContent is fals e, this is the default height if panel size is not defined
            theme               : 'default',
            autoPlayLocked      : true,
            delay               : 7000,      // How long between slideshow transitions in AutoPlay mode (in milliseconds)
            resumeDelay         : 10000, // Resume slideshow after user interaction, only if autoplayLocked is true (in milliseconds).
            pauseOnHover        : false,      // If true & the slideshow is active, the slideshow will pause on hover
            navigationFormatter : function(index, panel){ // Format navigation labels with text
                return ['<span class="carousel-text">PREVIEW OUR SHOW!</span>','<span class="carousel-text">HOWL ON NCL</span>', '<span class="carousel-text">HOWL 2-GO</span>', '<span class="carousel-text">BACHELORETTES!</span>',][index - 1];
            },
            onBeforeInitialize  : function() {$('#slider li img').hide()},    // Callback before the plugin initializes
            onInitialized  : function() {$('#slider li img').show()}      // Callback after the plugin has been initialized
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like there is a bug in the slider you're using. The "cur" class that is being added to items to show the active state isn't ever being removed. There's not much to be done other than to fix that bug.

Comment: You're using a really old version, try updating to the newest version: https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider

Comment: @Mottie Is updating this going to change the style of my sliders? I really can't have any down time and the site is very confusing. there are like 25 stylesheets and 5 htmls. I'm never sure which to update. It's working fine on the location pages

Comment: Also we are using Joomla 1.5. I guess you can't just update to the latest version because your theme will break. It's the worst.

Comment: hmm, well you could use the [`onSlideComplete` callback](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Callbacks-and-Events#onslidecomplete-null--slide_complete) to update the navigation correctly. But it is difficult for me to test it on your site when there are two copies of jQuery loaded on the page - remove the second one (below the `<!-- BirthdaySlider -->` comment).

Comment: @Mottie but that would break the slider at the bottom of this page http://www.howlatthemoon.com/birthday-parties

Comment: I created a different slider for this because I understand how to do it this way. With the original slider, I didn't install that and apparently you have to build it using like 3 different Joomla modules. This way I coded it all in HTML/CSS and I just had to put the JS code in the header. But unfortunately, with the line in the bday slider works but the home page breaks, but without it the bday slider wont work although the homepage is fixed. Isn't there a way to make that line work for both scripts?

Comment: That older version of AnythingSlider should work with the newer version of jQuery, try loading that newer version before AnythingSlider, but still remove the second copy of jQuery.

Comment: @Mottie Nope, it broke the other page. Check out the bottom: http://www.howlatthemoon.com/birthday-parties

Comment: Wait no, it was because the js was under <jdoc:include type="head" />  Once I moved it above everything worked. Thanks for your help!